# Excel VBA Advanced Filter, Filter everything BUT

Tags: vba, excel

let say I have a database of customers, internationally.

I know I can use advanced filter to copy all customers from United States, using criteria that looks like:

-

Country

United States

-

However, what if I want to filter everything BUT United states? is this possible?

My current solution is to use the AND operator by listing all the countries except US, which is not pretty.

Hope someone can help, and if this is a duplicate, please let me know. I tried searching with terms such as "excepting", "exception", "everything but" with excel advanced filter but did not find any.

Thanks,

Comment: It is possible. Do you want to use advance filter? Or you want formula filter data?

Comment: Just use: `<>United States` as your criterion.

Comment: question more suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using advance filter: Just use not equal operator in criteria range.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is formula for filtering your data. Its just a excel array formula. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($A$3:$A$9<>"USA",ROW($A$3:$A$9)),ROWS($A$3:$A3))),"")
```

[image]